# file /proc/cmdline is empty

Tags: linux, boot, proc, initramfs

I'm having a problem to boot my system, because the initramfs which should get its values from /proc/cmdline, such as the root device, isn't able to obtain any value, and that's because this file is empty. How can i fix this?

About:
LFS
Linux 4.19.80
Syslinux (although the same happens with Grub)

Comment: It might be that parameters are passed in device tree or that booting parameters are hardcoded. Does `/proc/config.gz` exist?

Comment: no, there's no /proc/config.gz, but i'm using the pre-compiled libre-linux from freesh, and in their site they give the config: https://linux-libre.fsfla.org/pub/linux-libre/freesh/configs/4.19/x86-64

Comment: At least with grub, you would expect to end up with a line like `linux /filename1 param1 param2 param3` and a second `initrd /filename2` to tell grub to load a kernel from filename1 and the initial ramdisk from filename2. The param1 param2 param3 stuff would go into memory and be accessed by the /proc/cmdline file. So are you providing this information, either by the commands you are giving to grub directly or via the grub.cfg file?

Comment: I'm not using grub, but i tried with it passing the arguments in the grub shell:
```linux (hd0,x)/boot/vmlinuz-4.19-80 flags;
initrd (hd0,x)/boot/initrd-4.19-80;
boot
``` But the flags didn't appeared inside /proc/cmdline, which was empty

Comment: You're within initramfs, so have you mounted the `/proc` filesystem yet at this point?

Comment: before trying to read the cmdfile i mount proc with `mount -t proc none /proc`, and i can attest that it was mounted correctly as the directory is populated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem, /proc/cmdline has a size equal to zero, and the cat(1) utility was optimized to use stat/mmap instead of read/write (the last one would be able to print the content).